# Disable incremental build for kapt

Tags: android, kotlin, annotation-processing, incremental-build

Since android gradle plugin has enabled incremental build by default annotation processing breaks, because only those classes who has been changed since last incremental build will be taken into account from annotation processors.

So for java source code we usually use `apt` grald plugin to run annotation processing. However, android's gradle plugin automatically disables gradle's incremental build feature if `apt` is used in the same project:
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/298

Now I'm working on a kotlin project and Im facing the same incremental build issue with `kapt`. So the solution, as with `apt`, is to disable incremental build. The documentation says:

```
android {

  compileOptions.incremental = false
  ...
}
```

However, that doesn't work for me. Does anybody know how to disable incremental builds?

Answer (score 4):

You can add

```
kotlin.incremental=false
```

to your `gradle.properties` file to disable the incremental building.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it seems to be fixed in version 1.0.4. Currently, it's still in the EAP phase so you'll have to add another repository.

```
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev' }
}
```

Then change the version to 1.0.4-eap-xx in your root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.4-eap-84'
    ...
}
```

Here's the link to the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12776).